# SQL Server Instance ID

Tags: sql-server-2008, instance

I'm looking for a way to identify a particular SQL Server Instance from a stored procedure within the server. What I need is to be sure that my app is connecting to that particular instance and not to some other instance with the same name/ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look at the [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) function - you could use a mixture of InstanceName, MachineName, ServerName or ProcessID for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
select  @@ServiceName
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using the [@@SERVICENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180056.aspx) function.

Here's the description from the [@@SERVICENAME MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180056.aspx)

> Returns the name of the registry key under which SQL Server is
>   running. @@SERVICENAME returns 'MSSQLSERVER' if the current instance
>   is the default instance; this function returns the instance name if
>   the current instance is a named instance.

The [@@SERVERNAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx) will return the name of the server the database is running on, which may also be helpful to you.

Usage example: `SELECT @@SERVERNAME as 'Server Name', @@SERVICENAME AS 'Service Name'`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the  instance id can be seen under following folder path

```
%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\<instance-id>
```